# Insert error in rethindb using node

Tags: javascript, node.js, rethinkdb

I am new to rethinkdb.
When I try out the sample code in https://github.com/rethinkdb/rethinkdb-example-nodejs/tree/master/todo-angular-express

```
function create(req, res, next) {
var todo = req.body;
todo.createdAt = r.now(); // Set the field `createdAt` to the current time

r.table('todos').insert(todo, {returnVals: true}).run(req._rdbConn, function(error, result) {
    if (error) {
        handleError(res, error) 
    }
    else if (result.inserted !== 1) {
        handleError(res, new Error("Document was not inserted.")) 
    }
    else {
        res.send(JSON.stringify(result.new_val));
    }
    next();
});
```

}

I got the following error:

> 500 Internal Server Error
>
> {"error":"return_vals renamed to return_changes in:\nr.table(\"todos\").insert({title: r.json(\"\"abcde\"\"), completed: r.json(\"false\"), createdAt: r.now()}, {returnVals: true})\n

And then I tried out the sample code in http://rethinkdb.com/docs/examples/node-todo/

```
function create(req, res, next) {
var todo = req.body;         // req.body was created by `bodyParser`
todo.createdAt = r.now();    // Set the field `createdAt` to the current time

r.table('todos').insert(todo, {returnChanges: true}).run(req._rdbConn, function(error, result) {
    if (error) {
        handleError(res, error) 
    }
    else if (result.inserted !== 1) {
        handleError(res, new Error("Document was not inserted.")) 
    }
    else {
        res.send(JSON.stringify(result.changes[0].new_val));
    }
    next();
});
```

}

I got the following error:

> 500 Internal Server Error
>   {"error":"Unrecognized optional argument `returnChanges`. in:\nr.table(\"todos\").insert({title: r.json(\"\"abcde\"\"), completed: r.json(\"false\"), createdAt: r.now()}, {returnChanges: true})\n                                                                                                                                         "}

It seems that rethinkdb have changed **returnVals** to **return_changes** / **returnChanges**, and the argument of insert().

And I have the problem fixed when I used **return_changes**.

What is the right way to work on insert in latest version?
Do rethinkdb always changes its syntax?

Answer (score 1):

this is indeed a bug in the example code. I've opened https://github.com/rethinkdb/rethinkdb-example-nodejs/issues/3 so we can fix it.

Your second problem with `returnChanges` not being recognized might come from using an old RethinkDB node driver. Have you tried updating the driver? http://rethinkdb.com/docs/install-drivers/javascript/